# How do I add dynamic labels in highcharts while using motion plugin?

Tags: r, highcharts

Is it possible to add a sequence of labels that update during motion? I can load a full vector or static value but nothing dynamic like the sequence/value combination.

For instance in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsac07/91waaLrc/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=91waaLrc) the time series of points is provided in the sequence array. Here's a snippet of the relevant part of that code:

```
 var data = [
    {
        "hc-a2": "NT",
        "sequence": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100],
        "value": 1100
    }, {
        "hc-a2": "WA",
        "sequence": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100],
        "value": 1100
    }, {
        "hc-a2": "CT",
        "sequence": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100],
        "value": 1100
    }
```

I'd like to include a label value that updates as the time series is scrubbed in the interactive so that on hovering the label could say something like "Western Australia - Population: 1100; Registered Voters: 800". The registered voter count would change over time but only appear in the label (not the visualization).

I'm using highcharter package in R.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic-labels in highcharts. You have to search that labels in highcharts. js,highchartsmore.js etc. included in your code.